# C flush buffer and get only one char

Tags: c

```
int main(void) {
    char type;
    while(scanf("%c", &type)) {
        printf("%c\n", type);
    }
}
```

I would like to get one character and do something in while loop. Unfortunetly when I type for example `yyy` while loop iterate 3 times. How can I flush or cut string for only one char?

This solution is still not working

```
int main(void) {
  int type;
  while((type = getchar()) != '\n' && type != EOF) {
    printf("%c\n", type);
  }
}
```

Comment: Use getch iinstead of scanf

Comment: Input to a string and take only the first `char`.

Comment: The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7898362/694576

Comment: This solution is still not working